# Как исправить ошибки компоновщика C++?

Tags: c++

Имеется класс, определеный в заголовочном файле. Его методы также определены в этом загол. файле. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы код методов был в отдельных `.cpp` файлах, но постоянно ловлю ошибку линковщика.

Например, есть три файла:

`1) BigInteger.h`:

```
#ifndef CPPBIGINTEGER_BIGINTEGER_H
#define CPPBIGINTEGER_BIGINTEGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

typedef vector<int> v;

class BigInteger {
private:
    bool sign;
    v absVal;
public:
    BigInteger() {
        foo(*this);
    }
    friend void foo(BigInteger& a);
};
#endif //CPPBIGINTEGER_BIGINTEGER_H
```

`2) foo.cpp`:

```
#include "BigInteger.h"

void foo(BigInteger& a) {
    a.absVal = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

`3) main.cpp`:

```
#include "BigInteger.h"

int main() {
    BigInteger a;
    return 0;
}
```

Во время компиляции `g++-5 main.cpp` получаю такую ошибку:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "foo(BigInteger&)", referenced from:
      BigInteger::BigInteger() in ccL6wDIn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Но если функция `foo` определена сразу после класса в `BigInteger.h`, то все нормально компилируется. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно компилируете. Вы должны указывать *все* cpp-файлы.

Попробуйте так:

```
g++-5 main.cpp foo.cpp -o prog
```

Если вы хотите компилировать cpp-файлы по отдельности, делайте так:

```
g++-5 -c main.cpp
g++-5 -c foo.cpp
g++-5 main.o foo.o -o prog
```

(А ещё лучше напишите makefile.)

Comment: Да, действительно, скомпилировалось. Но почему, когда я определяю конструктор в заголовочном файле, компановщик опять выдает ошибки? Вот заголовочный файл с конструктором: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/yutkin/a3b0a81c03b0c315a51b).

Comment: @0x1337: Потому что вы нарушаете one definition rule: функция может быть объявлена только в одном месте. У вас определение конструктора компилируется с _каждым_ cpp-файлом, который включает этот header! И компоновщик видит этот конструктор в каждом объектном файле. Либо вынесите тело конструктора в .cpp, либо определите **внутри класса**.

Answer (score 0):

`void BigInteger::foo(BigInteger& a)` - объявлен метод класса, а реализована простая функция.

Comment: Если я не хочу делать функцию - членом класса? Я просто хочу сделать её "дружественной", чтобы она могла иметь доступ к приватным полям. Я исправил определение функции в файле `foo.cpp` на `void BigInteger::foo(BigInteger &a)`, ошибка та же.